# Implementation of Interface Segregation Principle Example given in Uncle Bob's Agile Principles Book

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, agile

Is my implementation of Figure 12-1 correct?
[image: Figure12-1]

This is an implementation of Interface Pollution example from Uncle Bob's book Agile Principles Patterns and Practices in C#.

I have tried implementing it as following:-

```
using System;

namespace AgilePrinciplesCSharp.Chapter12.Listing12_2
{
    class Listing12_2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var door = new TimedDoor();
            var client = new Client(door);
            client.TimeOut();
        }
    }

    public interface ITimerClient
    {
        void TimeOut();
    }

    // We force Door, and therefore (indirectly) TimedDoor, to inherit from TimerClient.
    public interface IDoor : ITimerClient
    {
        void Lock();
        void Unlock();
        bool IsDoorOpen();
    }

    // Implementation of Door Interface with Timer functionality
    public class TimedDoor : IDoor
    {
        public bool IsDoorOpen()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Lock()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Door Locked");
        }

        public void TimeOut()
        {
            var timer = new Timer();
            timer.Register(5, this);
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout! Door left open for so long");
        }

        public void Unlock()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Door Unlocked");
        }
    }

    // Timer class can use an object of TimerClient
    public class Timer
    {
        public void Register(int timeout, ITimerClient client)
        {
            /* CODE */
        }
    }

    // Client uses Door Interface without depending upon any particular implementation of Door
    public class Client
    {
        IDoor door;

        public Client(IDoor door)
        {
            this.door = door;
        }

        public void TimeOut()
        {
            door.TimeOut();
        }
    }
}
```

My doubt is in the way the implementation is described in the book, where Door is sometimes being called as a class or sometimes as an interface and i am getting confused whether i need to have a separate implementation of Door class apart from IDoor interface?
Also the author does not use I notation while naming an interface which makes it even more confusing.

If anyone has read the book, i hope can understand my concern and help me out with this.

**NOTE: This Book can also be read online. This discussion is at page 215.**
https://druss.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Agile-Principles-Patterns-and-Practices-in-C.pdf

Comment: The book talks about interfaces, isn't explicit and doesn't use the `I` notation? Ditch it, I doubt there's anything good there

Comment: I started reading the book as it was highly recommended by the Udemy instructor Mosh Hamedani in one of his blogs:
https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/top-3-reads-for-csharp-developers/ 

I really liked Mosh's way of teaching and thought of giving his advice a try.

Comment: Somehow the figure seems wrong for me. Wouldn't it make more sense if TimedDoor implements the TimerClient and not Door, because a TimedDoor is a Door associated with a Timer/controlled by a Timer.

Comment: I have provided a link to read the content of the book in the question itself. Probably that would help.@ckuri

Answer (score 2):

I believe he is using UML class diagram notation, so this diagram would seem to apply:

[image]

[Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram).

If I read this correctly, `TimedDoor` should *inherit from* `Door`. But in your example, `TimedDoor` *implements* `IDoor`. That is not consistent with the diagram.

The declaration should be:

```
class TimedDoor : Door
```

I don't think you need an `IDoor`. What is germaine to the example is that `Door` must implement `ITimerClient` in order for a `Timer` to perform operations on it. `ITimerClient` should expose a single public member, `Timeout()`. Presumably when the timer calls this method, the door should unlock itself, if it is a timed door. The default behavior (e.g. for a non-timed door) is probably no-operation.

```
interface ITimerClient
{
    void Timeout();
}

class Door : ITimerClient
{
    public virtual void Timeout()
    {
        //No operation; this isn't a timed door
    }

    //etc.
}

class TimedDoor : Door
{
    protected bool locked = true;

    public override void Timeout()
    {
        this.Unlock();  //Override default behavior because this type of door is timed
        base.Timeout();  //Optional, sometimes recommended
    }

    public virtual void Unlock()
    {
        this.locked = false;
    }

    //etc.
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how i implemented it before.
But then i wondered, how will the Client decide which kind of object it needs.
(Which should be an interface type so that it does not depend on any particular implementation)
And therefore we need to take care of those inheritances/implementations (of interfaces) as well?

Comment: Or if we go by your implementation, should the client accept any door which implements ITimerClient?
(Doesn't sound like a correct design approach)

Comment: There is no `Client` in the diagram. What is its purpose? If it isn't to call `Timeout()` on something, it probably doesn't need to know about `ITimerClient`.

Comment: Ok. Fair Enough.
However, the interface needs to declare the TimeOut method as a virtual one for this implementation to be correct (otherwise it will give a compile Time error).
But if you see in the book the Author hasn't made it Virtual, which is another reason i am a lil hesitant to accept this as the correct implementation.

Comment: Interface members don't really take access modifiers in c#. They are always public. The diagram seems to omit any mention of `Door` or `TimedDoor` having properties or methods, so there is nothing that he should or should not have marked virtual. I think it is for brevity.

Comment: Sorry, My Bad! I was trying to implement interface method TimeOut() as Timeout().  [Spelling mistake]. Once i corrected it, i was able to use it as a virtual method.